# Using os.popen() or subprocess to execute functions

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I'm currently studying threading, multiprocess, and os documentations to improve the structure of my program. However to be honest to me, some of it is sophisticated, I can't get it to implement on my program, either it crashes due to stackoverflow, or gets the wrong ourput or no output at all. So here's my problem.

Let's say I have a list of names that gets passed into a function and that function is what I want to run in another console with - ofcourse a python interpretter. and have it run there in a full cycle.

Let's say I have this:

```
def execute_function(name, arg1, arg2):
   While True:
       #do something

for name in names:
   execute_function(name, arg1, arg2)
```

what should I use in order to run this function to open another console programatically on python and run it there `While True:` is it subproccess/multiprocess/threading or perhaps `os.popen()`?

And how should I execute,  in this example? The multiprocessing Pool and Process always crashes with me. So I think its not the right solution. So far from what I've searched I haven't seen examples with threading and subprocess being used with functions. Is there a workaround on this? or perhaps a simple solution I might have missed? Thanks.

Edit:

A similar code:

```
     if symbols is not None and symbols1 is not None:

         symbols = [x for x in symbols if x is not None]
         symbols1 = [x for x in symbols1 if x is not None]
         if symbol != None and symbol in symbols and symbol in symbols1:
              with Pool(len(exchanges)) as p:
                   p.map(bot_algorithm, (a, b, symbol, expent,amount))
```

http://prntscr.com/j4viat - what the error looks like

Comment: can you post the code that's crashing as well?

Comment: Are you trying to get another console to open and run your script, or are you fine with a background process/thread that will run in the same console?

Comment: it's branching with more functions, so I'm afraid, the question might not become "concise" if I add it there. And I tried running a simple function. And multiprocessing doesn't achieve my goal in popping out another console so its currently at the last priority. But if there;s away to use that and open such console to test the scripts.

Comment: @MadPhysicist im trying to get another console to run the script, so I can see the flags I've put in the function.

Comment: @deku, what we ask for isn't your original code, but the smallest/simplest code that can be written to let someone else produce the same problem, test their proposed answers, etc. See the [mcve] definition, and/or the [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) definition.

Comment: [`os.popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen) is essentially just a wrapper around `subprocess.Popen`, so which you use is a just matter of how much control you want over starting the process.

Comment: @deku. Conceptually, we are asking that you put as much effort into your question as you expect us to. As phrased right now, someone that is not a mind reader will not likely be able to help you much, so your question is more likely to get closed than to get a proper answer.

Comment: BTW, if you want to open a new terminal window for this function you should call that out loudly and explicitly -- I'd put it in the title. The word "console" is somewhat vague, so right now it's fuzzy as to whether that's really what you intend. (And when you say "function" -- do you really mean a Python function, ie. that you could fork off a copy of the same interpreter and invoke it directly with no `execve` syscall?)

Comment: As another aside -- temporarily self-deleting your question will let you modify it without worrying about close votes / downvotes / etc. coming in  in the interim, and then undelete it when you're finished making improvements; whereas if others delete it by vote, a new vote is required to reopen it later.

Comment: Please don't post errors and code as screenshots. Use text with proper code formatting for anything that comes from the console.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for mentioning about it. I edited and added the part

Comment: @MadPhysicist Can't seem to copy-paste it from console. unlike when using jupyter. sorry about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subprocess` is <strike>always</strike> usually preferred over `os.system()`.

The docs contain a number of examples - in your case, your `execute_function()` function might want to use `subprocess.check_output()` if you want to see the results of the command.

eg.:

```
def execute_function(name, arg1, arg2):
  output = subprocess.check_output(["echo", name])
  print(output)
```

All this does though is launch a new process, and waits for it to return. While that's technically two processes, it's not exactly what you'd call multi-threading.

To use run multiple subprocesses at synchronously, you might do something like this with the multiprocessing library:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

def execute_function(name, arg1, arg2):
  return subprocess.check_output(["echo", name])

names = ["alex", "bob", "chrissy"]

pool = Pool()

map_results = pool.map(execute_function, names)
```

this maps an iterator (the list of names) to a function (execute_function) and runs them all at once. Well, as many cores as your machine has at once. map_results is a list of return values from the `execute_function` func.

Comment: At least in Python 3, `os.popen` is just a wrapper around `subprocess.Popen`, hiding arguments you probably weren't going to use anyway. You might be thinking of `os.system`.

Comment: This is probably helpful even if it's unclear what OP actually wants

Comment: I'd still say `subprocess.Popen` is always preferable to `os.system`; `os.popen` provides a simpler interface to certain uses of `subprocess.Popen` that you might choose if it is sufficient.

Comment: Why the *always* is striked through? It *is* **always** preferred over `os.system`.

Comment: @Bakuriu. Because there are exceptions to every rule

Comment: Thanks! This does work! But how do I check whats going on with the subprocess? Actually, my programs running so fast, I can't check whether the sub is running with it or not.(if it runs with the main console). @DanielleM.

Comment: @deku I'll update the example to collect the results from the execute_function ... function

Comment: @MadPhysicist Not really. That's a dumb statement to justify something.  If you have *any* situation where `os.system` would be preferred over the `subprocess` module, go ahead and show one.

Comment: @Bakuriu. When you are typing it by hand in the shell.

Comment: @MadPhysicist `call('ls')` is still shorter than `system('ls')`.